# Use of mysqldump option --single-transaction

Tags: mysql

In tables like `InnoDB`, `MyISAM` etc engines. 
When we use mysqldump with option `--single-transaction` etc. whats the use of that option?
i.e. see the code here.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h ${HOST} -u${SOURCEUSER}  -p${SOURCEPASS} \
    --skip-add-drop-table -t --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --skip-add-locks --complete-insert -q -e --skip-disable-keys \
    --where="ID=${ID}" \
    ${SOURCEDB} ${SOURCETABLE} | sed -e "s/INSERT INTO/REPLACE INTO/" | sed -e "s/${SOURCETABLE}/${TARGETTABLE}/g" |  /usr/bin/mysql -u${TARGETUSER} -p${TARGETPASS} ${TARGETDB} ;
```

Please explain! Thanx!

Comment: NO one answering ! why?

Comment: what are you asking? meaning of `--single-transaction` ?

Comment: Not asking the meaning.I want to use of that option when we do the mysqldump.

Comment: I'm unable to understand your query. Can you try to edit your question and make it more understandable :)

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal please check the edit one!

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Yes your answer is correct but I want some more about that.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Yes I will. but, see the comment that I have pasted beloved  your answer.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal can we chat on gmail,Its better to communicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting directly from dev.mysql.com

> This option sets the transaction isolation mode to REPEATABLE READ and sends a START TRANSACTION SQL statement to the server before dumping data. It is useful only with transactional tables such as InnoDB, because then it dumps the consistent state of the database at the time when START TRANSACTION was issued without blocking any applications.

If you need to read more :

> When using this option, you should keep in mind that only InnoDB tables are dumped in a consistent state. For example, any MyISAM or MEMORY tables dumped while using this option may still change state.
>
> While a --single-transaction dump is in process, to ensure a valid dump file (correct table contents and binary log coordinates), no other connection should use the following statements: ALTER TABLE, CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE, RENAME TABLE, TRUNCATE TABLE. A consistent read is not isolated from those statements, so use of them on a table to be dumped can cause the SELECT that is performed by mysqldump to retrieve the table contents to obtain incorrect contents or fail.
>
> The --single-transaction option and the --lock-tables option are mutually exclusive because LOCK TABLES causes any pending transactions to be committed implicitly.
>
> To dump large tables, combine the --single-transaction option with the --quick option.

Here is the url : [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction)

Comment: Actually I knows this link. But, I want to know more meance, If MyISAM tables are there and we doing the mysqldump and used there --single-transaction then waht will happen it ignore transaction or keep it.?

Comment: @Pranjal you should mention that in your question and everything else too. That's why there are downvotes on it. I'm still not getting your point. You need to know what will happen if mysql transactions are not successfully completed?

Comment: Yes If suppose I have moving more than 2 corore rows and the above code that,I have pasted ..using that code I have inserting rows from one table to another.So, Is is transaction or not?

Comment: I'll try to cover what I'm understanding. If a transaction fails in mysql ,then transaction in progress is rolled back. database instances jump from 1 consistent state to another. also quoting above lines , `When using this option, you should keep in mind that only InnoDB tables are dumped in a consistent state. For example, any MyISAM or MEMORY tables dumped while using this option may still change state.`
For 2 crore rows of big heavy data , again quoting above lines
`To dump large tables, combine the --single-transaction option with the --quick option. `